# Java - Add custom event Listener to a eventSet in beanInfo with Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, addeventlistener, javabeans, beaninfo

i have a custom bean and a custom eventListener, i need to show my event Listener in the events tab of my bean.

I think the solution is to add my event Listener to a beaninfo(i create it with netbeans, so it is auto-generated).
There is a "wizard-way" to do this, or i have to hand-write my beaninfo?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to have all methods for listener management, so Netbeans can recognize it and put it inside beaninfo.

For example, if you have a custom listener called ActionDataListener, you have to add this methods:

```
    public void addActionDataListener(ActionDataListener listener) {
        actionDataListeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeActionDataListener(ActionDataListener listener) {
        actionDataListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public ActionDataListener[] getActionDataListeners() {
        return actionDataListeners.toArray(new ActionDataListener[0]);
    }
```

Comment: The getActionDataListeners method is not required, just the add and remove methods. As illustrated, it is important also that the add<X>Listener(<X>Listener listener) naming be used. It is possible to use an inner interface like add<X>Listener(Parent.<X>Listener listener). But naming like add<X>Listener(<Y>Listener listener) won't work.